Why does grep-apply-setting exist; why couldn't I just use setq
The documentation says that if I Want to update, for example, grep-find-command, I should use grep-apply-setting.  There is no documentation on that function explaining why it exists.  Looking at the code, it appears to maintain different values for grep-find-template (and the rest) based on the hostname on whichgrep will run.
Is that the reason it exists?  if I run emacs and open local files on my Windows machine, and remote files via tramp on machine1, I would want different grep commands?

As described by grep-find-command doc, it is modified at runtime depending on the circumstances. This means that if you setq it to some value, your value may get overwritten. Quote:

In interactive usage, the actual value of this variable is set up by ‘grep-compute-defaults’; to change the default value, use M-x customize or call the function ‘grep-apply-setting’.

Its initial value will be computed at runtime by function grep-compute-defaults, which sets grep-host-defaults-alist and a number of other variables. And then, what grep-apply-setting does is it changes the grep-host-defaults-alist in such a way so that the value you set will persist as opposed to being potentially changed to something else.
